# Combine Comparators in java

Tags: java, comparator, chaining

I have 2 comparators:

```
Comparator<? super MyClass> COMPARATOR_BY_PRIORITY =
        Comparator.nullsFirst(
                Comparator.comparing(c -> c.isEmpty() ? null : -c.getPriority())
        );

Comparator<? super MyClass> COMPARATOR_BY_PRICE =
        Comparator.nullsFirst(
                Comparator.comparing(c -> c.isEmpty() ? null : c.getPrice())
        );
```

and I'd like to combine them, so that using the combined comparator would sort the items 1st by priority, and between the items with the same priority by price. How do I create a combined comparator?

I'm trying something like:

```
Comparator<? super MyClass> COMBINED_COMPARATOR =
    COMPARATOR_BY_PRIORITY.thenComparing(COMPARATOR_BY_FARE);
```

Comment: What about your solution, doesn't help you?

Comment: no, it doesn't compile, there's no thenComparator that can get a Comparator

Comment: I think your comparators should be `Comparator<MyClass>`. With `Comparator<? super MyClass>`, you allow those to `compare` instances of `Object`, but those do not have the methods that are needed for comparison. (Not sure why you can define it like that in the first place, I try not to think about `? super X` too much...) This also fixes the problem with `thenComparing`.

Answer (score 1):

As @tobias_k pointed out it works without the ? super:

```
Comparator<MyClass> COMPARATOR_BY_PRIORITY =
        Comparator.nullsFirst(
                Comparator.comparing(c -> c.isEmpty() ? null : -c.getPriority())
        );

Comparator<MyClass> COMPARATOR_BY_PRICE =
        Comparator.nullsFirst(
                Comparator.comparing(c -> c.isEmpty() ? null : c.getPrice())
        );

Comparator<MyClass> COMBINED_COMPARATOR =
    COMPARATOR_BY_PRIORITY.thenComparing(COMPARATOR_BY_FARE);
```